# C# LinqToSql LoadOption with pattern repository

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

In the project i am maintaining, i have refactoring few logic using the repository pattern over the old ORM (LinqToSql).

My problem now is sometimes i have to share DataContext across repository (this is a desirable feature) but those repository try to "steal" each other the loading option.

Here an example of my repository constructor, that receive the DataContext and build the proper loading option.

```
    public ArticleRepository(DataContext datacontext) : base(datacontext)
    {
        this.Name = "ArticleRepository";

        lock ( _sync )
        {
            this.Datacontext = datacontext; // --> this is done in base class, assing the shared object to the current repository.
            this.Datacontext.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

            DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
            options.LoadWith<tbl_ana_Article>(article => article.UoM);
            options.LoadWith<tbl_ana_Article>(article => article.Brand);
            this.Datacontext.LoadOptions = options;
        }
    }
```

But i have also OrderRepository which it's own loading option.

The problem arise when i use such repositories on the same DataContext :

```
using ( var context = new MyDatacontex("...") )
{
    var articleRepo = new ArticleRepository(context);
    var orderRepo = new OrderRepository(context);// <-- here the loading option are overwritten

    articleRepo.DoStuff();
    orderRepo.DoOtherStuff();

    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Now in this specific case, i can reorder operation and avoid problems but it's a very specific and fragile solution.

I don't know if i have to specify a loding option in the constructor, save it in the object, and overwrite the shared datacontex property before each datacontext use (read). Is this a good solution or there is a better one?

Comment: The fact you have such trouble should tell you you're using the wrong pattern. That DataContext is already a Unit of Work with one repository member per entity type. It caches all changes for all entities and persists them when `SubmityChanges` is called. On the other hand, LInq-to-SQL isn't just old, it was never meant to be a full-featured ORM. It was quickly replaced by Entity Framework

Comment: `those repository try to "steal" each other the loading option.` these aren't each other's options. They apply to the entire DataContext. You're trying to put a low-level single-entity repository wrapper over a higher level, multi-entity DataContext. A DataContext instance represents a single transaction, loading and modifying only the entities needed for a specific use case. It's not a model of the entire database and *shouldn't* try to map all tables. It only needs to map the tables needed for its specific use case. It's perfectly fine to have multiple contexts with different entities

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: if i have unerstand, the question is that i should not have "shared boundaries". Each domain has his repository, with it's own datacontext and they never share nothing. Problem is that a so strict modelling risk (IMHO) to be too costly in my scenario, so i have relaxed thing a bit. There are situation (like this) in which the domain that  handle shipping has to work with the domain that handle articles, so they can work althogether, atomically. Let me know if something is broken in my picture.Thanks again for your help, and my apologies for my english (not mother tongue)

Comment: Wrong. The domain repository here is the DataContext itself. If you want to use Domain Driven Design, a DataContext is used to persist entities in a Bounded Context and is meant to load aggregate roots. If you want to abstract the DataContext, you need to create a repository that handles the entire Bounded Context, not the individual entities

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ah.. so i am a bit lost sorry. In my idea i have many linq2sql model, one for each domain. Article and Order should be separated, but because sometimes they need to cooperate i have choose to put them in the same datacontext even if they have two different repository. Usually repository for Article and Order work alone, but when needed they cooperate (as in the uploaded code). At that point it seems to me that considering the datacontext like a domain is a good idea, and so i may put both the loading option in this specific datacontext factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `Context` is a same object, you have to prepare it before use. It's a complex scenario so you have to be warned about state of "Context Options" before any usage. If you change it before specific usage, the next usage must clear last options or set its own options. Best approach could be that you set options before usage and return it to previous state after usage so it would be all clear. But in async scenarios there is a chance that you see a behavior that you didn't expect.

An other note, some options are shared and some of them are not. For example `DeferredLoadingEnabled` is a shared setting and `LoadWith` is a specific option. You can decide to make shared setting fixated and set all specific options once in `Context` constructor.

Comment: really good idea the initial setup i will investigate the faseability in my scenario